# Lost in Visual Studio 2017 settings -- how to set up indenting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, code-formatting

I'm sorry if I'm asking something obvious. I've been using an older version of VS but recently had to switch to VS 2017 and now I'm lost in all the fluff in it. I'm trying to set up the indenting for C# code. The easiest way is to show with a screenshot:

[image]

So how do I make it put a tab there after I hit return from those two points in code that I showed with arrows?

1. After the || operator
2. After the opening {

Comment: Do you use resharper, or just vanilla VS?

Comment: VS2017 isn't bad at formatting but you can't beat Resharper (@TheGeneral doh beat me again! :)  )

Comment: Just the vanilla VS. I went to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# and modified something there. Now I can't undo it.

Comment: @MickyD hahah, slow day at work here :P

Comment: I was trying to stop it from formatting (i.e. adding spaces) into code or comments that I was pasting.

Comment: OK, found it. Whoever else is interested: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> tabs -> Indenting -> Set to "Smart". (Yeah, well named item, hah.) This will take care of the issue I described in the screenshot. The question remains though, who tf made it "so easy" to navigate through VS settings.

Comment: @c00000fd answer your own question and mark it as correct, so other people can find this information too

Comment: Try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/999b219z(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs -> Indenting -> Set to "Smart".